# ssh-key with multiple algorithm/cipher

Tags: encryption, ssh

How can I create a ssh-key with the following algorithm and cipher?

diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr
hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512

Also, how can I check an existing private/public key have these algorithm/cipher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those are parts of the key itself. They're all part of the SSH session; all of them are negotiated as the session is established, and only if there's mutual support from the client and server processes.

If you want to see what your client supports,

- `ssh -Q kex` will show you key exchange algorithms (`diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` is one of those, but you might have others)
- `ssh -Q cipher` will show you symmetric encryption ciphers (`aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr` are three of those, but you might have others)
- `ssh -Q mac` will show you message authentication algorithms (`hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512` are two of those, but you might have others)
- `ssh -Q key` will show you key signing algorithms (you didn't list any in the original question; RSA, ECDSA, and Ed25519 are common ones, but you might have others)

Comment: Thanks JIm, so what command do I need to use to generate one key pair?

Comment: The basic command is `ssh-keygen`, but the arguments will depend on what you need and what your client and server support. `man ssh-keygen` will list all possible arguments, but the ones you should really look at will be `-t` (type) and `-b` (size; only relevant for RSA and ECDSA types).

Comment: Thanks again, we disabled the following ssh-rsa
Cipher Algorithms
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
and now getting "algorithm negotiation error", so to solve this error I generate a key pair with ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp521

Comment: That's `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521`.

Comment: I will try to create a key pair with ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521, thanks